# Ag Grid and Reactive forms

Tags: angular, ag-grid, angular-reactive-forms

I have a component it uses a `reactive form` and an `angular grid`. I am loading data in the form and in the grid. The data is editable and the user can click a button save and store it.

Unfortunately the form knows nothing about the data of the grid. If the form would know the data of the grid I could get the whole data by `this.myFormGroup.value` and I could known if there are changes by `this.myForm.valueChanges` (in the form and in the grid).

I am doing that to get the form data and to know if the form data has changes. But separately I am getting the data of the grid via `forEachNode` and the events `cellValueChanged + rowDataUpdated`.

Which strategy are you using to detect changes on components with reactive forms and angular grid and to send the data in backend? I am sure, there is a straightforward way.

**Update:**

I want to load a model (data) from backend and bind the model to a reactive form.

Original model from backend:

```
{
"firstName":"Paul",
"lastName":"Smith",
"address":{
"street":"228 Park Ave S",
"city":"New York",
"state":"USA",
"zip":"10003"
},
"gridData":[{'empId': 'A1', 'empName': 'A', 'skill': 'A'}]
}
```

The user makes changes and when the user saves the changes I want to take the updated model like this.myForm.value. It returns directly my model bound to the form. I would like that the rows of the grid are also included in the bound model returned when I am calling this.myForm.value.

Model updated:

```
{
"firstName":"John",
"lastName":"Smith",
"address":{
"street":"18 Green Aloyse S",
"city":"New York",
"state":"USA",
"zip":"2222"
},
"gridData":[{'empId': 'A1', 'empName': 'A', 'skill': 'A'},
 {'empId': 'A1', 'empName': 'A', 'skill': 'A'},
 {'empId': 'B1', 'empName': 'B', 'skill': 'B'},
 {'empId': 'C1', 'empName': 'C', 'skill': 'C'},
]
}
```

How do you build the updated model that will be send to the Server?

Comment: What does grid has to do with any kind of form besides layout?

Comment: I want to extract the data of my model and send it to backend. A part of the model is loaded in a from and the other part loaded in a grid. I want to extract data from the grid and from the form. Can I keep the data central and extract it in one step and not a part from the grid and the other from the form?

Comment: Explain what you wanna to achieve cuz current explanations is little bit weird.

Comment: I want to load a model (data) from backend and bind the model to a reactive form. The user makes changes and when the user saves the changes I want to take the updated model like `this.myForm.value`. It returns directly my model bound to the form. I would like that the rows of the grid are also included in the bound model returned when I am calling `this.myForm.value`. What are you doing in this case? It is a very typical case....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your question, it seems your implementation fits into option 3 as described in this excellent [example](https://medium.com/ag-grid/using-angular-forms-with-ag-grid-1efe00265535) written by Ag grid framework expert himself.

It basically comprises of

- creating dynamic reactive form controls and binding it to grid (using
  Form Array)
- listening to row data changes and refreshing form controls also clearing out old form controls

Comment: The solutions in the article does not work we I make the grid columns editable.